# Can't customize pushViewController's back button

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I've got a ViewController which opens up another ViewController by

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Now the new VC has got a back button in the navBar but I can't manage to give it the same background image as the navBar buttons from the first ViewController. I've tried with:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Button.png"];
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"doesnt work either"];
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try code snippet give below, it works fine for me:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pop)];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
```

Or you can do this as well:

```
   UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26)];
   [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [backButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
   [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerWithAnimation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
   UIBarButtonItem *barBackItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBackItem;
```

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you but I can't get it to work. With your first code piece the button stays black and with the second there is no button at all :(

Comment: Second option is woking fine, just now i have implemented sample example with the same code. Are you following these:

1. Implement this code in your VC1 > viewDidLoad (VC1 is the view controller which has been pushed)
2. Change image name to your custom image name

I have also tried with setting bgcolor of button, and that also working fine

Comment: Nice. Sorry, just commenting so I can find this tomorrow morning.

Comment: @MusiGenesis : If you are upvoting my answer, then I don't have any problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(pushNav:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
         self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

      -(void)pushNav {
           [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
      }
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. The button stays black. It doesn't seem to be exchanged at all because on tap it doesn't call pushNav: but just pops the view as standard :(